# Email & Password Verification in swift5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

email and password validation in ios swift5:

error:

> 1.Cannot find 'isValidEmail' in scope

> 2.Declaration is only valid at file scope

```swift
let email = txtemail.text
guard txtemail.validate([isValidEmail]) else {
    print("Invalid email/password. Please try again.")
    return
}
```

```swift
extension String {
//Validate Email
    var isEmail : Bool {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}", options: .caseInsensitive)
            return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) != nil
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }

    var isAlphanumeric: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && range(of: "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", options: .regularExpression) == nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You extended the string so you should call its check. Also `txtemail` is probably an `@Outlet` so we need to unwrap its text. Afterwards we check the String if it's valid.

```swift
guard let email = txtemail.text, email.isEmail else {
    print("Invalid email/password. Please try again.")
    return
}
```